# Windows : security of USBNET / RNDIS

Tags: network, windows, usb

I'm having trouble finding documentation about how to setup any security for RNDIS or if the system is already secure enough.

For those who doesn't know [RNDIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNDIS) is a protocol that permits a USB connected device to interact with the computer, and even send requests through the computer to the network. This is done by emulating a network interface in a private network, so the IP of the connected device is not seen from the said network.

From what I saw, it doesn't seem to have any way of specifying which devices are allowed to connect to the computer (whitelist). So is this safe or should I just let it for development and only setup some WiFi networks for my clients? Which may be sensitive to security.

Comment: The last two phrases are unclear. What is the link between WiFi and RNDIS?

Comment: @DeerHunter none, those are two way of doing the thing : either setting up a wifi network so the device can communicate with the server, or setup RNDIS so the device will communicate with the server through the computer.

Comment: I can see now. In general, you'd prefer to have the same tech in dev and production.

Comment: Yes of course, the internal validation will be on the same way as we do with the client, but i can't setup a private wifi where i am. Aniway the question is to know if RNDIS can be secured so only allowed compoments could make requests to the network through the computer. Because basically once you have allowed the devices to send requests to the computer's network, it's for all devices. So maybe there is a way to prevent this but i don't find anything on the net. Another way would be a little soft that secure traffic between the network interface and the RNDIS interface on the computer.